# ¿Qué término se usa en psicología para "closure"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico

> **Closure** or **need for closure** (**NFC**) are psychological terms that describe *an individual's desire for a firm answer to a question* and an aversion toward ambiguity.
>
> <sub>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(psychology))</sub>

***Closure*** viene a ser algo que encontramos después de una mala experiencia que nos ayuda a dejar esta experiencia atrás y seguir adelante con nuestra vida.

Por ejemplo, en [Funeral de Graham Lukas](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tsz4xlc73dihtpnf6qbjxjlvjre?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics), una canción sobre su propio funeral, dice:

> Now it's over (over) // Oh it doesn't mean it's **closure**

"Ahora se ha terminado //Oh, no significa que sea ???"

¿Qué término se usa en psicología para ese "cierre"? A mi sólo se me ocurre "pasar página", pero es demasiado informal. [Catarsis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7v4biYD) no parece adecuarse en este contexto, ya que aunque es un acto de "liberación" no es un acto de "purificación".

Comment: Un dicho más o menos cercano: **_borrón y cuenta nueva_**, "olvidar lo pasado y volver a empezar". Desconozco si solo es un chilenismo.

Comment: Lo que he visto que usan es **hacer el duelo** en el sentido de afrontar una pérdida y continuar adelante con la vida.  https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duelo_(psicolog%C3%ADa)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pesar de que la canción de Graham fue lo que me animó a investigar el término un poco más, quizá no sea el ejemplo más representativo del uso de "closure" en psicología (o yo no lo interpreté bien).

Ha hecho falta preguntarle a un psicólogo (licenciado y colegiado) para entender que, de acuerdo a la definicion de wikipedia, el termino correcto seria "certeza" o "necesidad de certidumbre".

> An individual's desire for a firm answer to a question and an aversion toward ambiguity. (Definición de *psicological closure*)
>
> Necesidad de buscar certeza, no tolerar incertidumbre ni ambiguedad, y buscar reaseguración (que me confirmen si algo es así o no).
>
> Del DRAE [certeza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8OPnJP9):
>
> 1. f. Conocimiento seguro y claro de algo.
> 2. f. Firme adhesión de la mente a algo conocible, sin temor de errar.

El termino "certeza" se emplea en psicología como tal, aunque parece ser que también existe el más llamativo "**necesidad de cierre cognitivo**".

Quizá la canción hace uso de de una definición "tradicional" de `closure` (frente al uso del término en psicología) definido como:

> A sense of resolution or conclusion at the end of an artistic work.

Que sí podría traducirse como `cierre`, `clausura`, "necesidad de cierre", etc.

Comment: cierre me parece un buen término para psicología. http://glosarios.servidor-alicante.com/psicologia/cierre

Answer (score 2):

**Fin de historia**, o **el fin de la historia**.  Yo conozco esta frase así:

> ¿Eso es todo?  ¿Te vas, así nomás, sin discusiones, fin de historia? [End of story]

Pero podemos retomar esta frase para tu ejemplo también:

> Now it's over (over) // Oh it doesn't mean it's closure
>
> Ya [se] terminó la cosa // Ah, pero eso no quiere decir que sea fin de historia

Con esto quiero decir que el capítulo no se ha cerrado todavía.  La historia sigue corriendo en la mente de la persona que no ha logrado hacer *closure* todavía.

Podrías decir que lo inventé -- pero creo que funciona bastante bien.  Porque cuando aceptas que es fin de historia, no sigues dando vueltas y vueltas al asunto.

Comment: Me parece una traducción plausible (+1), pero no parece un término sacado del vocabulario técnico usado en psicología.

Comment: Me gusta mucho "Ya se ha acabado, pero no significa que sea el fin" porque suena como letra de canción. Acabo de leer la letra de la canción que nos diste en el enlace (que debería de haber hecho antes de escribir mi respuesta). Me parece que el narrador está diciendo, "Me voy a morir, pero aún después de la muerte no te voy a dejar en paz." Dado mi odio por este tipo de actitud, me es difícil encontrar algo mejor. Sería más fácil considerar el otro punto de vista -- "Ya te moriste, necesito *closure* para seguir con mi vida sin tí." Si imagino a la persona que sobrevive, hablando con...

Comment: ... el psicólogo: "Ya se murió mi amado. Me hubiera gustado hacer las paces con él antes que se muriera, para poder seguir adelante con mi vida. Sin eso, doy vueltas y vueltas a nuestra relación, pensando en mis errores, sus errores, nuestros malentendidos, todo lo que podría haber hecho mejor. Quisiera encontrar paz, tranquilidad."  Es decir, la persona que sobrevive hubiera querido ***despedirse*** del que se murió.

Comment: Veo que tu interpretación es más positiva.  Si supongo que es acertada, entonces quizás: "Aunque ya se habrá acabado nuestra relación cotidiana, todavía estaré contigo en el corazón."  Pero eso no concuerda con lo que yo entiendo por *closure*.

Comment: Creo que el sentido de la canción de Graham es "que mi funeral sea una fiesta!!" Va a haber un barman poniendo copas a la salud de Graham (estáis todos invitados) y más vale que todos los colegas se emborrachen. Dice "Ha sido una buena vida. Yo ya no estoy a pesar de lo unidos que éstabamos. Se que no es suficiente para **pasar página/seguir adelante** (tras mi muerte), pero os quiero y os veo y os custodiaré desde arriba".

Comment: @Diego - "no es suficiente para pasar página/seguir adelante (tras mi muerte)" - se entiende bien tu traducción pero les aconsejaría a los seres queridos de este tipo que se despidieran de él de una vez. Creo que fue precisamente para evitar este tipo de situacion que los psicólogos inventaron el término *closure*.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el *closure* de la canción y el término psicológico no se pueden traducir de la misma forma. En la canción yo lo traduciría simplemente como *fin*:

> Ya se ha acabado, pero no significa que sea el fin.

Sin embargo, como término psicológico ya no sé exactamente qué expresión se usa, aunque podríamos decir ***poner un punto y seguido*** (o ***un punto y aparte***, según como de dura sea la experiencia), como metáfora de que una parte de la historia de uno ha terminado, y hay que comenzar con la siguiente. En todo caso, tu opción de ***pasar página*** no me parece mal, dado que *[página](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RRvUbbP)* se define como:

> Suceso, lance o episodio en el curso de una vida o de una empresa.

"Pasar página" significa, pues, terminar un episodio en la vida y empezar con el siguiente.

Comment: Es posible, Pensaba que Graham decía "no es _closure_" en referencia al "And don't be so sad // 'Cause I lived this good" queriendo decir "No nos veremos más pero no estés triste. Yo estoy satifecho con lo vivido. Aun así entiendo que no puedas _pasar página_ así como así". Pero tienes razón, es un poco ambiguo. Viendo que el término se usa en psicología, supuse que habría un equivalente en español. En cualquier caso, +1