# ¿Tiene la palabra "perversión" una connotación negativa?

Tags: definiciones, sustantivos, dle

A ver, voy a explicar un poco de dónde sale esta pregunta no sea que penséis mal de mí, aun a sabiendas de que me puedo estar metiendo en otro de mis famosos [berenjenales](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5NIOz0T). Hablando con unos colegas sobre ofertas de trabajo uno usó las siglas SM para referirse a un Scrum Master, solo que a mí esas siglas me trajeron a la cabeza la palabra "sadomaso" (cosas que pasan). Así que ya aproveché la coyuntura y me dio por buscar la palabra en el diccionario a ver que ponía.

Y me encuentro con esto:

> **[sadomasoquismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WyEiqak)**
>
> Del ingl. *sadomasochism*, de *sado-* 'sadismo', 'sádico' y *masochism*
>   'masoquismo'.
>
> 1. m. Perversión sexual de quien goza causando y recibiendo humillación y dolor.

Compruebo que las definiciones de *[sadismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WyEEBZ0)* y *[masoquismo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OY59QJu)* también comienzan con "perversión sexual". Con estas definiciones el DLE me da a entender que está definiendo estas prácticas de forma subjetiva, valorando lo que debería ser una "inclinación" o "preferencia sexual" como una "perversión". Y ahí es cuando pregunto: ¿realmente definir algo como "perversión" es negativo? ¿Consideráis la palabra "perversión" como peyorativa o como portadora de una carga de subjetividad?

Nótese que estoy hablando únicamente de las definiciones sobre preferencias sexuales, otra cosa muy distinta son las otras acepciones de las palabras *sadismo* ("crueldad refinada") y *masoquismo* ("complacencia en sentirse humillado").

---

<sub>**Descargo de responsabilidad:** de verdad que no he practicado el *sadomaso* en la vida, es solo que no considero que se pueda llamar *perversión*
a algo que dos (o más) adultos deciden hacer libremente y sin coacción y siempre que no dañen a nadie más (que no sean ellos, claro).</sub>

Comment: Me imagino que la RAE irá revisando sus definiciones "a petición" de las preferencias y pataleos de la época.

Comment: Dices tú de berenjenales, el otro día casi hago un chascarrillo con que iba a elegir un texto de "50 sombras de Gray" para el próximo translation-golf, y luego decidí quedarme calladito, que yo también me [metí una vez en un berenjenal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19857/5481) por estos lares de la forma más tonta...

Comment: @Diego anda ya, si aquella pregunta fue muy entretenida. Además, a mí al menos me sirvió para aprender a no dar por supuesto nada, que yo pensaba que "bombilla" era la palabra de uso en todas partes.

Comment: Y yo daba por supuesto que así se decía en México y por eso pregunté por "sudamérica" queriendo decir "otros países de américa latina". Pero vamos, estuvo bien que me hicieran notar que andaba perdidísimo en mis referencias geográficas. A partir de entonces voy con más cuidado :-D

Comment: @walen creo que la inquietud de Carlos se debe más a una preocupación por que se genere un debate/confrontación/jaleo inútil en los comentarios, más que a que a él le tachen personalmente de lo que sea. Comparto que la pregunta, en la descripción del contexto, roza un tema sensible donde hay gente con fuertes opiniones enfrentadas, pero la pregunta está bien planteada. Ya aprovecho y aviso: como ya sabéis, si empieza a haber problemas con comentarios fuera de tono, inapropiados o insultantes, poned un flag y que se encarguen los moderadores.

Comment: ¿Cuándo lo *kinky* pasa a ser *perversion*?  Ni la Corte Suprema de EEUU lo pudo definir.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to ask a moral question rather than a linguistic one.

Comment: @aparente001 eres libre de votar como quieras, pero permíteme aclarar que la pregunta en realidad no tiene que ver con la moral, aunque el trasfondo sí lo sea: ¿tiene la palabra "perversión" un sentido negativo o peyorativo? El resto es solo por dar un contexto, pero puedes eliminarlo y quedarte únicamente con la pregunta sin contexto alguno.

Comment: "Bad" era malo.  Ahora depende del contexto.  Me imagino que "perversión" podría esta sujeta a estos matices modernos (¿posmodernos?).  Linguee daría pistas rápidas del rango de usos.

Comment: Ya que estamos en éstas, yo opino que a ningún sadomasoquista le gustaría que dejaran de considerarlo perverso.

Comment: @Rodrigo - Hmm.  Estoy imaginando una escena que podría salir en una película de Almodóvar: dos prostitutos/as comparando a los clientes, a fulano le gustan las perversiones vainilla, a mengano le gustan más, no sé, más guácala.

Comment: Cf. https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390349/112436

Comment: @aparente001 muchísimas gracias por tu idea de publicar la pregunta en [English.SE]. Están teniendo allí la discusión sana que yo esperaba que tuviera lugar aquí, y las respuestas están siendo de muchísima utilidad (sin desmerecer en absoluto la de Diego, por supuesto, que está redactada con gran acierto en mi opinión).

Comment: Qué bien que la discusión ahí te parezca útil.  Hoy alguien comentó en chat: "The psychology-psychiatry-psychoanalysis community has come to the consensus that humans have a wide spectrum of sexual behavior and it is a continuum from what society considers 'normal' to what society previously considered 'perversion.' "  No sé si eso te ayuda pero me pareció muy acertado.

Comment: Carlos, si quieres colaborar para aceptar una respuesta en ELU, me invitas a Chat por favor.  Pero no te desesperes si tardo en contestar en estos días.

Answer (score 2):

Esto iba para comentario, pero se me quedaba largo, y al final tengo que meter yo también mi propio descargo de responsabilidades.

Yo creo que *perversión* sí tiene connotaciones negativas. Por definición, la acción de [pervertir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SleUNlE)  es

> Viciar con malas doctrinas o ejemplos
>
> Perturbar el orden o estado de las cosas

La calificación de ciertas prácticas sexuales como *perversión*, [filia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HuXMHmC) o [parafilia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rpz3Ty5) puede depender ya de muchas otras cosas.

En el sexo es especialmente  fácil tachar muchas cosas como "desviación". Atención a [esta entrada](http://psicopsi.com/diccionario-de-psicologia-letra-P-Perversion-terminos-de-psicologia) del diccionario de psicología que dice que existe perversión en la homosexualidad por la forma en que define "la norma" o "lo normal".

> **Perversión**: Desviación con respecto al acto sexual «normal», definido como coito dirigido a obtener el orgasmo por penetración genital, con una persona del sexo opuesto.
>
> Se dice que existe perversión: cuando el orgasmo se obtiene con otros objetos sexuales (homosexualidad, paidofilia, bestialidad, etc.) o por medio de otras zonas corporales (por ejemplo, coito anal); cuando el orgasmo se subordina imperiosamente a ciertas condiciones extrínsecas (fetichismo, transvestismo, voyeurismo y exhibicionismo, sadomasoquismo); éstas pueden incluso proporcionar por sí solas el placer sexual.

Y aquí viene mi **descargo de responsabilidad**, voy a pedir ayuda a alguien en el campo de la psicología (como [otras veces](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20629/5481)) para validad si es cierto que el diccionario de psicología dice eso o no, solo por no incluir algo que no sea cierto en esta entrada.

Para contestar tu pregunta "pervertir" y "perversión" sí tienen connotaciones negativas. Si ciertas prácticas son *definidas* como tal (*perversión* frente a *preferencia*, como bien apuntas tú), ya puede depender de muchas cosas (al igual que mi *inclinación* o *dependencia* a contestar preguntas en este sitio. Cuando es una "cosa" sana" y cuándo tengo un problema? El diccionario recoge "definiciones" pero para juzgar si un comportamiento está dentro de lo "sano" o lo "dañino" o "(auto)destructivo" lo conveniente sería usar otros recursos).

---

Actualización:  Tras consulatar a un psicólogo licenciado este primero descarta la validez de ese "diccionario de psicología" y aclara que "lo normal" es "lo que abunda". En psicología se define `Trastorno` como cualquier conducta que afecta negativamente a a algún área de la vida (laboral, sexual, de salud, familiar...). El sadomasoquismo no es que abunde mucho pero no necesariamente es de forma automática un problema (o conducta negativa).

Lo más relevante para esta entrada es una aclaración de que en los manuales de la OMS de enfermedades mentales está el "Trastorno de identidad de género", no es que sea en sí una enfermedad, pero se incluye porque provoca mucha confusión en quienes lo sufren (Como un "trastorno de ansiedad". La ansiedad puede ser un mecanismo evolutivo y de supervivencia necesario. Eso no hace a la ansiedad mala, pero en según qué circunstancias se  puede decir que alguien sufre un "trastorno de ansiedad").

Así que sería objetable decir que el diccionario se *excede* en su juicio de valor al tachar el sadomasoquismo como perversión.

Comment: Pero ¿no podemos usar *perverso* para significar *anti-algo*?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, Diego, por ser el único que se ha tomado (hasta ahora) esta pregunta realmente en serio.

Comment: @vorbote es una idea interesante la que comentas, podrías plantear una nueva respuesta para así tener más opciones que votar.

Comment: ¡Je! La respuesta arriba era para @aparente01 (me sonrrojo).

Comment: @vorbote entonces sí es una nueva respuesta. Diego afirma que sí tiene connotaciones negativas, tú dices que es neutra, así que nos vendría bien tener los dos puntos de vista

Comment: @vorbote creo que debo aclarar: "perversión" tiene claras connotaciones negativas, viendo la definición del DRAE ("perversión" es "viciar/perturbar"), pero en lo que respecta al contexto de la pregunta, creo que mi respuesta hace énfasis en que algo no es "perversión" o "vicio" de por si solo por "contradecir la norma". De ahí incluso las aclaraciones en la actualización. Cuando se dice que el SM es "perversión" de por sí se entra en un juicio de valor (como calificar el juego o la bebida de problema). El DRAE no describe por ejemplo _fumar_ como un hábito pernicioso, cuando es bien sabido.